# Recognizing MainBody in PartBodies in a catia part using VBA

Tags: vba, catia

Catia contains a body that cannot be deleted in its tree structure in a part and boolean operations on that body cannot be performed (except "remove lump"), this body is called `MainBody` (I have read about it on different pages not sure whether it's called `MainBody`).

So the question is, how do you recognize `Mainbody` in the Catia VBA (code)?

Here are some screenshots of the body in the UI to help visualise what I am trying to do:

[image: This image shows Mainbody a Part]

[image: This image shows a Normal Partbody in the same Part]

Comment: ok, this will not happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *MainBody* is accessible directly from the *Part* (for example):

```vb
Set oMainBody = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Part.Mainbody
```

Also, this body belongs to the *Bodies*-Collection of the part.